# Returning a count of grouped items in peewee ORM

Tags: python, mysql, orm, peewee

I am trying to query a list on a unique field, and also the count of each unique field using peewee ORM. I can get what I want easily from MySQL workbench, however I can't seem to get a similar result out of peewee. The working MySQL query looks like this:

```
select Title, Severity, count(*) from qmodel group by Title;
```

I have tried a few variations in peewee but nothing is has worked. This is about as close as I have gotten:

```
from application.database.models import qmodel as q 

_field_select_list = [
    q.Title,
    q.Severity,
    fn.COUNT(q.Title),
]

for record in q.select(*_field_select_list).group_by(q.Title):
   print record
```

This returns the count, but replaces the title field on the return with the count, no title ( example `{'Severity': '3', 'Title': '25'}`)

I also made my field select look like this:

```
_field_select_list = [
    q.Title,
    q.Severity,
    fn.COUNT(SQL('*')),
]
```

But that just gives me a grouped list, no count. I have tried many other combinations with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to do something like this:

```
query = (QModel
         .select(QModel.title, QModel.severity, fn.COUNT(QModel.id).alias('ct'))
         .group_by(QModel.title, QModel.severity))
for obj in query:
    print obj.title, obj.severity, obj.ct
```

Note, in most databases you need to group by every column you select that is a non-aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just leaving the `COUNT` function empty? It works fine for me on my data.

```
query = q.select(q.Title, q.Severity, fn.COUNT()).group_by(q.Title)
```

Comment: This gives me a syntax error. I tried that very early on as it seemed like it would definitely work from what I had seen. Now I am even more perlexed that it would work for you. Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I was testing quickly with sqlite. Just tried it with MySQL 5.5 and received a syntax error as well. So at least it's consistent. I'm experimenting with different drivers and MySQL setups.

Comment: Oddly, `q.select(q.Title, q.Severity, fn.COUNT(SQL('*'))).group_by(q.Title)` works perfectly for me using MariaDB 10.10. Have you tried that? Checking logs, this yields the equivalent query to the working one you mentioned above.

Comment: No error using `SQL('*')`, but also not the intended result. I also tried double quotes. I get my title and field value, but no count.

Comment: Weird, try using `.tuples()` to see the count.

Comment: It IS invalid SQL. You need to include all selected columns that are not aggregates in the group by. So add Severity to the list of group_by(...) columns and it should work.